# Should I dispatch an action when typing?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm working with a small project using ReactJS and Redux. I stored data in Redux store and looking for good practice on how to update data in there. I can pass data from store to state and update state every time I type, then update state to store, but I wonder is that a good way to do, or I should update store immediately when typing? Is there a performance issue?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) If the input value is not required by other components (be it sibling, parent, or even unrelated components), there is not need to persist it on your store. You should just encapsulate it within your component's state

```
[inputvalue, setInputValue] = useState('');

<input value={inputvalue} onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
```

2) If it is required by other components, you choose to keep the input in store. Do take note that if you follow this approach, you will have to update the store at every instance the input value has changed.

Assuming that it is a connected component,

```
const { inputValue, updateInputValue} = props;

<input value={inputValue} onChange={(e) => updateInputValue(e.target.value) }
```

3) If there are any side effects (such as fetching of data from external API) that arise from input change, you might want to debounce the firing of the side effect.

Comment: @Riya nahhh don't worry!

Comment: You need to also consider re-rendering. The internal state might update just the input component, whereas state update might unnecessary re-render more components